# Getting Exception when connecting to WCF service from silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf, wcf-client

When am trying to connect to the wcf service from silverlight am getting the following exception and here am using the crossdomain.xml and Clinetaccesspolicy file also

**Exception : CommunicationException was Unhandel by the usercode**

> An error occurred while trying to make
>   a request to URI
>   'http://localhost:3500/WCFService/Service.svc'.
>   This could be due to attempting to
>   access a service in a cross-domain way
>   without a proper cross-domain policy
>   in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may
>   need to contact the owner of the
>   service to publish a cross-domain
>   policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.
>   This error may also be caused by using
>   internal types in the web service
>   proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute.
>   Please see the inner exception for
>   more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the crossdomain policy xml in the hosted application.

See [Cross Domain Policy](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx)

This is because Silverlight is like a client application and it will make wcf service calls to http://../somesite. The crossdomain policy xml says that it accepts calls from otherdomains(i.e Silverlight XAP file which is loaded in the client browser.)

Comment: Everything is fine in my application as discussed in the blog ..any other idea

Comment: Have you added the crossdomainpolicy.xml in the same directory as the .svc file?

Comment: Run your application in Firefox with Firebug extension. See the requests being made. If some request are failing for any of the cross domain policy file, check to which url is the client connecting to. That is the location where the policy file should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to implement the [Silverlight fault behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) too to see the actual error